# How to not see "None" output when getting user input(): input(print("Your key:"))

Tags: python, python-3.x

When I use `input()` I am also using `print` to print the info inside my input function like this:

```
access = input(print("Type the key that you want: "))
```

But when I run the function I get the input message to input the values but below it, I have `None` like this:

> Type the key that you want:
>
> None

I will also let one image to you check it better.

[image: None unexpected]

I don't want this `None` output, just the output message to the user input the data. What can I do to remove this `None` output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Likely, what you want is:
`access = input('Type the key you want')`

Even though the `print()` function displays outputs to your terminal, it doesn't **return** anything, hence why `print(access)->None`

Comment: this is close but not quite right. `input(print("give some input"))` will first print the line give some input. then the return value of print will be passed to input, so input receives `None` and input prints the None value. then waits for the user the value returned to access will be what ever the user typed

Answer (score 2):

The `input` method does not need a `print` method.

Just do:

```py
access = input('Some prompt text:\n')
```